# Palindrome Induction Proof

Tags: induction, palindrome

Consider strings made up only of the characters $0$ and $1$; these are binary strings. A binary palindrome is a palindrome that is also a binary string.

(a)Let $f(n)$ be the number of binary palindromes of length $2n$, for $n\ge  0$. Discover a formula for $f(n)$. Here are two pairs to get you started: $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = 2$, $\ldots$. (Notice that we are concerned only with even-length binary palindromes.)

(b)Prove that your formula is correct for all $n\ge  0$, using simple induction.

I get that the formula would be $f(n) = 2^n$, but I'm having difficulty proving this. I am new to induction, so I am unsure where to begin. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Seems easier without induction  (as you get a palindrome by taking whatever you like for the first $n$ and then repeating it backwards).  To do it with induction, Hint:  remove the first and last characters.  What remains is a palindrome with 2 fewer entries.

Comment: im confused because im not sure what i'd be proving. i know that we are proving n + 1, so we would have to prove: f(n) = 2^(n + 1), but what are we proving that this is?

Comment: I'll write up more details and post them below.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods:

Direct Approach:  To make a palindrome of length $2n$ we may choose the first $n$ however we like, then repeat the string backwards.  But there are $2$ ways to choose the first character, $2$ ways to choose the second, up to $2$ ways to choose the $n^{th}$ so there are $2^*2^*\dots^*2=2^n$ ways to do it.

Induction:  It is easy to verify the formula for small $n$ (but you should be sure to do it!).  Assume we have done it for $n-1$.  Thus we know there are $2^{n-1}$ palindromic strings of length $2(n-1)$.  Now, to make a palindromic string of lenght $2n$ we choose one of length $2(n-1)$ and select a character (either $1$ or $0$) to surround it (one in front, one at the end).  There are, by induction, $2^{n-1}$ ways to choose the string of length $2(n-1)$ and $2$ ways to choose the surrounding character so all in all there are $2^*2^{n-1}=2^n$ ways to make our string of length $2n$, as desired.